# How to refer to the collection of horizontal line characters?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

Hyphens, dashes, n-dashes, m-dashes, and minus signs all look the same (give or take a pixel).  Is there a term for this set of characters?

Comment: Probably, if one needed to refer to them, they could be called simply _dashes_, as you have it already, or _dash characters_ to make it clearer.

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed, Unicode calls all such characters ones with the `Dash` property. There were 27 of these last time I looked.

Answer (score 6):

Unicode now calls all of these "Dash" characters (meaning, they have the "Dash" property, not that their names mention *dash*):

```
U+002D ‭ -  HYPHEN-MINUS
U+058A ‭ ֊  ARMENIAN HYPHEN
U+05BE ‭ ־  HEBREW PUNCTUATION MAQAF
U+1400 ‭ ᐀  CANADIAN SYLLABICS HYPHEN
U+1806 ‭ ᠆  MONGOLIAN TODO SOFT HYPHEN
U+2010 ‭ ‐  HYPHEN
U+2011 ‭ ‑  NON-BREAKING HYPHEN
U+2012 ‭ ‒  FIGURE DASH
U+2013 ‭ –  EN DASH
U+2014 ‭ —  EM DASH
U+2015 ‭ ―  HORIZONTAL BAR
U+2053 ‭ ⁓  SWUNG DASH
U+207B ‭ ⁻  SUPERSCRIPT MINUS
U+208B ‭ ₋  SUBSCRIPT MINUS
U+2212 ‭ −  MINUS SIGN
U+2E17 ‭ ⸗  DOUBLE OBLIQUE HYPHEN
U+2E1A ‭ ⸚  HYPHEN WITH DIAERESIS
U+2E3A ‭ ⸺  TWO-EM DASH
U+2E3B ‭ ⸻  THREE-EM DASH
U+301C ‭ 〜 WAVE DASH
U+3030 ‭ 〰 WAVY DASH
U+30A0 ‭ ゠ KATAKANA-HIRAGANA DOUBLE HYPHEN
U+FE31 ‭ ︱ PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EM DASH
U+FE32 ‭ ︲ PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EN DASH
U+FE58 ‭ ﹘ SMALL EM DASH
U+FE63 ‭ ﹣ SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS
U+FF0D ‭ － FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS
```

There used to be a "Hyphen" property but it was supplanted by the word-break properties.